# How to connect component in Spark when data is too large

Tags: scala, apache-spark, merge, bigdata

When dealing with component connecting of big data, I find it very difficult to merging them in spark.

The data structure in my research can be simplified to `RDD[Array[Int]]`. For example:

`RDD[Array(1,2,3), Array(1,4), Array(5,6), Array(5,6,7,8), Array(9), Array(1)]`

The objective is to merge two Array if they have **intersection set**,  **ending up with arrays without any intersection**. Therefore after merging, it should be:

`RDD[Array(1,2,3,4), Array(5,6,7,8), Array(9)]`

The problem is kind of component connecting in Pregel framework in Graph Algo. One solution is to first find the edge connection between two `Array` using *cartesian product* and then merge them. However, in my case, there are **300K** `Array` with total size **1G**. Therefore, the time and memory complexity would be roughly **300K*300K**. When I run the program in my Mac Pro in spark, it is completely stuck.

Baiscally, it is like:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, but 1G is not big data... How is that too large? Most Macs have about 8G RAM nowadays, right?

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes, 1G is not big data, but eventually I will extend my algorithm to big data. My Mac truly has 8G RAM. Therefore, if I cannot run this dataset in my Mac, it means that the algo is not desirable enough.

Comment: I don't have any particular code in mind, but I'm not so sure Spark is really meant for this particular algorithm/task. I've done something similar with dataframes and SparkSQL, and used Windowing functions, but I was guaranteed consecutive numbers. It doesn't appear you have that

Comment: @cricket_007 I add a picture to illustrate the objective. In fact, similar algo can be found in spark GraphX, [link](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/graphx-programming-guide.html) in **Connected Components**.

Comment: Personally, I don't understand connected components completely, and your arrays have no explicit connections between them until you tell Spark that they do. In other words, the only reason you can form your expected output is because you, as the developer, knows mathematical constructs of intersections and number ranges.. connected components will not merge the arrays for you, it just assigns component ids for each component. You still have to find a way merge the arrays

Comment: @cricket_007 yes. However, to assign the component ids, I need to first find the connection between clusters, such as `(from, to)`. I cannot find a good way to do this when data is big.

Comment: There's no need for a cartesian up front. Keep a set of currently disjoint arrays, Traverse your list, updating the set with the merge of the current array if it intersects with one of the existing members, add the current array if it doesn't. At the end, replace the original list with the resulting set, repeat, until no changes are made. You can do this per-partition (it's basically an `aggregate`) and then across partitions.

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul Hi, could you provide some code for the problem? Thanks. I am new to Spark, and I have trouble in how to find intersection across two partition in `aggregate`.

Comment: "could you provide some code for the problem?" Sorry, no. I don't have time right now.

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul Thanks again! I have applied your inspiration to implementing codes, and it works! In fact, I find that spark official website [link](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html) seems to  offer no description on this operation.

Comment: Feel free to [edit] your post to include code that you are trying. If "it works" means that you have an answer, feel free to answer your question below to share your work

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. Might not be decent enough, but works for a small data. Whether it can apply to large data needs further proof.

`def mergeCanopy(canopies:RDD[Array[Int]]):Array[Array[Int]] = {
    /*
    try to merge two canopies
     */
    val s = Set[Array[Int]]()
    val c = canopies.aggregate(s)(mergeOrAppend, _++_)
    return c.toArray`

`def mergeOrAppend(disjoint: Set[Array[Int]], cluster: Array[Int]):Set[Array[Int]] = {
    var disjoints = disjoint
    for (clus <- disjoint) {
      if  (clus.toSet.&(cluster.toSet) != Set()) {
        disjoints += (clus.toSet++cluster.toSet).toArray
        disjoints -= clus
        return disjoints
      }
    }
    disjoints += cluster
    return disjoints
  }`